# X-axis tick labels different font size and font face ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

Different font size and face to the x axis tick labels.

Solution:
- I tried using bquote and atop. It worked! Thanks for all the help!

Comment: The `ggtext` package might help, it lets you use markdown to specify text. This would give you some control over font face and size. https://github.com/clauswilke/ggtext

Comment: Thank you @KentJohnson. I will look into it.

Answer (score 3):

Try adding

```
+ theme(axis.text.x = element_text(color = "grey20", size =c(12,8), face=c("bold","plain")
```

Did this solve your problem?

Comment: Thank you @Christian Mirian Larsen. It alternates bold and plain labels for the tick labels. But I am trying to get plain and bold variation within a single tick label.

Comment: I have tried using atop and scriptstyle(). It seems to work. Thanks for your help.